# Can I automatically connect to an ESXi server when I start vmware workstation?

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation, esxi

I use Workstation as my main client for managing the VM's on my ESXi server, which I do by connecting to it as a remote server.

To save me from having to do this every time I start up Workstation, **can I autoconnect to my server whenever I start up Workstation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of.  If I remember correctly, VMware Workstation (Pro) for Linux might allow specifying a `-H` command-line option to specify a host to connect to (along with `-U` to specify a username).  Due to different implementations of handling command-line options, I don't think this works in the Windows version of VMware Workstation where I believe it requires a VM to be specified.

So on Windows, while you generally can't make VMware Workstation automatically connect to just a server, you *can* make it connect to a specific VM on that server, which might be almost as good.

The easiest way to do this would be to connect to the server, show the Library, and drag a VM from the library onto your Desktop or other folder.  Double-clicking on the created shortcut will launch Workstation (if not already running) and connect to the specified VM.